# how to call a field of a django model from the id?

Tags: django

I cant find the error in this code 
the code call a model id from select and store it in a variable , after i need to recupere two champs of models and store like a char in array

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#resoudre").click(function(){
            var strVehicules = $('#vehicule_sel')[0].value.innerText;
            var vehicules = strVehicules.split(" ");
            var idDemandes = $('#pt_collecte')[0].value;
            p = PointCollecte.objects.get(id=idDemandes);
            var strDemandes = (p.Latitude,p.Longitude);
            var demandes = strDemandes.split(" ");
         });
    });
</script>
```

fichier models.py

```
class vehicule(models.Model):
Matricule = models.CharField(max_length=50)
Marque = models.CharField(max_length=50)
Type = models.CharField(max_length=50)
Capacite = models.CharField(max_length=50)
date_mise_en_circulation = models.DateField(null=True)

def __str__(self):
    return self.Matricule

class PointCollecte(models.Model):
Nom = models.CharField(max_length=50)
Latitude = models.CharField(max_length=50)
Longitude = models.CharField(max_length=50)
Qtmoyenne = models.FloatField()
```

template .html

```
<form>
        <div class="form-row">
            <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                <label for="pt_collecte">Les points De Collecte a visités </label>
                <select multiple class="form-control" id="pt_collecte">
                    {% for PointDeCollecte in pt_collectes%}
                        <option value="{{PointDeCollecte.id}}">{{ PointDeCollecte.Nom }} </option>
                    {% endfor %}
                </select>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                <label for="vehicule_sel">Les véhicules a utilisés </label>
                <select multiple class="form-control" id="vehicule_sel">
                    {% for vehicule in vehicules %}
                    <option value="vehicule.id">{{ vehicule.Matricule }}</option>
                    {% endfor %}
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-md-4">
            <button id="resoudre" class="btn btn-primary my-1">valider </button>
        </div>
    </form>
```

Comment: you want to call python code inside javascript?

Comment: Here's the issue `p = PointCollecte.objects.get(id=idDemandes);`
You are in `javascript` but asking to execute `python` code. That can't work.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you're asking for python code to be executed in a javascript block.

```
p = PointCollecte.objects.get(id=idDemandes);
```

Most people would use a `$.getJSON` request or something similar. 
However, if you're only trying to get longitude and latitude you could do something like this:

```
{% for PointDeCollecte in pt_collectes%}
    <option value="{{PointDeCollecte.id}}" data-long="{{PointDeCollecte.Longitude }}" data-lat="{{ PointDeCollecte.Latitude }}">{{ PointDeCollecte.Nom }} </option>
{% endfor %}
```

Then you could get the data values from javascript, since they would be available in the DOM.
See: https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/

Comment: I did that but no change (see the answer below)